# How can I verify mining progress?

Tags: mining, mining-pools

[image: Screen Shot]Been at this for 1/2 a day now. How do I know if I'm getting anywhere? It's all very much Greek to me. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are mining DCR from supernova and ETH from ethpool.  To check your accounts, visit each of the sites and input the address you are mining to (your DCR address at supernova will differ from your ETH address at ethpool.

The sites should then show what your respective addresses have been credited with.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey....thanks for your reply. But I guess my question is, am I mining to anywhere? When I enter my account number I get 0's all across the board. Is that typical for ~1 day mining in a pool? On the site, says my Hash Rate = 0 (although console shows ~10-20Mh/s). I appreciate that is not exactly blazing speed but shouldn't it at least have made some progress (ie, coin!). Any input welcome. Cheers

Comment: Give it a couple of days. From your screenshot, looks like its working properly. Also, wouldn't hurt to double check that the address you are mining to is accurate.

Comment: Another stupid question (I'm full of them!). How do I mark it as answered?